# Splitting Data Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Hello everyone i have data like this;

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -- state: US state (by number) - not counted a... | but if considered | should be consided nominal (nominal) |
| -- county: numeric code for county - not predi... | and many missing values (numeric) | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... |

But i would like to transform into this;

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| state | US state (by number) - not counted a ... but if considered | should be consided nominal (nominal) |
| county | numeric code for county - not predi ... and many missing values (numeric) | NaN |
| ... | ..... | .... |

or simply;

| 0 |
| --- |
| state |
| country |
| .... |

and i wrote this code, but i wonder that is there any possible way to do that quicker..

```py
variable_names = pd.read_csv("path", header = None)

df = variable_names[0]
df = df.str.split(': ', expand = True)

df = df[0]
df = df.str.split('-- ', expand = True)
```

Comment: What kind of file are you reading, what is the delimiter and what does the raw file look like?

Comment: please explain what is the use of this line in your code `data = pd.read_csv("path", header = None)` ? I don't see it used anywhere

Comment: @SammyJ I wrongly paste it, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is:

```
# This becomes a pandas dataframe.
variable_names = pd.read_csv("path", header = None)

# Using simple apply works on all rows.
variable_names[0] = variable_names[0].apply(lambda x:x.split(': ')[0])
variable_names[0] = variable_names[0].apply(lambda x:x.split('-- ')[1])
```

Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, but it kinda same. I wanted use like that;
`df.str.split('-- ', ': ', expand = True)` like that or equivalent